# Domain creation script broken when upgrading 10.3 to 10.3.3

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I have a python script which creates a domain in our weblogic installation.
When I upgraded to 10.3.3 the script no longer works.
I get the following error:

```
 [exec] 
 [exec] Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
 [exec]   File "/home/sbaker/workspace/fire_trunk/mig/weblogic/domain_v10/build/gsDomainCreation/gsDomain.py", line 65, in ?
 [exec]   File "/home/sbaker/bea/wlserver_10.3/common/wlst/modules/jython-modules.jar/Lib/javaos.py", line 32, in ?
 [exec]   File "/home/sbaker/bea/wlserver_10.3/common/wlst/modules/jython-modules.jar/Lib/re.py", line 7, in ?
 [exec]   File "/home/sbaker/bea/wlserver_10.3/common/wlst/modules/jython-modules.jar/Lib/sre.py", line 17, in ?
 [exec]   File "/home/sbaker/bea/wlserver_10.3/common/wlst/modules/jython-modules.jar/Lib/sre_compile.py", line 15, in ?
 [exec] AssertionError: SRE module mismatch
```

Line 65 is: fileQueueName = os.environ['FILE_QUEUE']

I have tried putting in an: print os.environ, but that also fails saying the same thing.
I suspect the os.environ no longer exists. If so, what has it changed to?

Thanks in advance,
Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Python is looking for one version of a library and finding another.

Make sure your environment is set up as specified on this page: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/config_scripting/using_WLST.html.  Sometimes if you have two versions of python on your machine and in the system PATH then you can get the SRE error.  Make sure you are running the setWLSEnv script to set up your environment, and that you have only one set of Python libs on your classpath.